# Rewrite a For Loop that Calculates Percentage Column when Total is in a Row Using Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I would like to rewrite the for loop code below in Tidyverse syntax using dplyr, tidyr and purrr.

```
for (i in seq_along(Data3)) {
Data3[[i]]$Count <- as.numeric(Data3[[i]]$Count)
n <- nrow(Data3[[i]])
Data3[[i]]$perc <- Data3[[i]]$Count / Data3[[i]]$Count[n]
}
```

Sample data below:

```
Loc<-c("Montreal","Toronto","Vancouver","Quebec","Ottawa","Hamilton","Total")
Count<-c("2344","2322","122","45","4544","44","9421")

Data<-data_frame(Loc,Count)
Data2<-data_frame(Loc,Count)
Data3<-list(Data,Data2)
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

Each dataframe has "Total" within the "Loc" column with the corresponding overall total of the "Count" column. I would like to calculate percentages for each dataframe by dividing each value in the "Count" column by the total, which is the last number in the "Count" column.

I would like the percentages to be added as new columns for each dataframe. 
For this example, the total is the last number in the column, but in reality, it may be mixed anywhere in the column and can be found by the corresponding "Total" value in the "Loc" column.

I've been playing around with using purrr::map but I'm not sure how to calculate the percentage.

```
Data3%>%map(~mutate(.x,paste0(round(100*  (MISSING PERCENTAGE),2),"%"))
```

Comment: This site is not for 'write my code' questions. What have you already tried, what didn't work, or where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I added an example of what I have in mind for code but I'm really stuck on the percentage calculation. I tried looking for other posts about this but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use base R:

First ensure that your data has Loc as characters and not factors:

```
 Loc<-c("Montreal","Toronto","Vancouver","Quebec","Ottawa","Hamilton","Total")
 Count<-c(2344,2322,122,45,4544,44,9421)

 Data<-data.frame(Loc,Count,stringsAsFactors = F)

 Data3<-list(Data,Data)

 lapply(Data3,function(x) {x[,"Percentage"]=100*x[,2]/x[x[,1]=="Total",2];x})


 [[1]]
         Loc Count  Percentage
 1  Montreal  2344  24.8805859
 2   Toronto  2322  24.6470651
 3 Vancouver   122   1.2949793
 4    Quebec    45   0.4776563
 5    Ottawa  4544  48.2326717
 6  Hamilton    44   0.4670417
 7     Total  9421 100.0000000

 [[2]]
         Loc Count  Percentage
 1  Montreal  2344  24.8805859
 2   Toronto  2322  24.6470651
 3 Vancouver   122   1.2949793
 4    Quebec    45   0.4776563
 5    Ottawa  4544  48.2326717
 6  Hamilton    44   0.4670417
 7     Total  9421 100.0000000
```

There is no quite big difference between `map` in `purr` and `Map` in Base R. if your aim was to indeed use `map`. then I can give a tip like below which will give the same solution as above, logic being almost similar:

```
Data3%>%map(~mutate(.x,'%'=100*Count/Count[Loc=="Total"]))
```

I used the % sighn.. I could have written percentage...

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the "Total" rows, this would perform your task. However, mixing values of differing types in a single column is a very untidy form for your data. Proceed at your own risk.

```
Data %>% 
  mutate(Count_type = ifelse(Loc == "Total", "Total", "Component") %>% 
  group_by(Count_type) %>%
  mutate(Count_pct = Count/sum(Count))
```

The better solution is to simply strip out the "Total" rows, since they can easily be computed as an extra column  whenever you desire.

```
Data %>% 
  filter(Loc != "Total") %>%
  mutate(Count_pct = Count/sum(Count))
```

As far as `Data3`, is there a reason you're storing your dataframes in a list? You're right that `purrr` can solve that problem, but there are much simpler ways:

```
Data3 <- bind_rows("Data" = Data, "Data2" = Data2, .id = "Source") %>% group_by(Source)
```

Then just substitute `Data3` as the start of either of the above pipelines.

If you're using a list because your data is coming to you as a list for some reason, your `map` code is close to correct. You should be able to figure out how to use these snippets to work on a list of dataframes.